# NSIS not resolving magic variables in the proper way?

Tags: sql-server, nsis

I try to install MS SQL 2008 R2 with NSIS so I use this code snippet:

```
SetOutPath "$TEMP\Unit\DimIns\binary\SQLSVR"
File /r "..\..\shared-binaries\download.unit.hu\MsSQLServer2008R2\SQLSVR-x86\"
SetOutPath "$TEMP\Unit\DimIns\"ExecDos::exec "$OUTDIR\binary\SQLSVR\setup.exe /QUIET  /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ConfigurationFile=$OUTDIR\binary\SQLSVR\dimsqlsetup.ini /ACTION=Install" "" "$OUTDIR\MsSQLServer2008R2.log"
```

But it will fail. And it output this error message:

```
The following error occurred:
The action type 'ExecuteWorkflowAction' is not valid for the WorkflowIdentity element.      The only valid action type is ExecuteWorkflowAction.

Error result: -2068709375
Result facility code: 1202
Result error code: 1

Please review the summary.txt log for further details
The following error occurred:
The action type 'ExecuteWorkflowAction' is not valid for the WorkflowIdentity element.      The only valid action type is ExecuteWorkflowAction.

Error result: -2068709375
Result facility code: 1202
Result error code: 1

Please review the summary.txt log for further details
Microsoft (R) SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup 10.50.4000.00

Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

But if I explicit give the path

```
ExecDos::exec "C:\Users\UNIT-TEST\AppData\Local\Temp\Unit\DimIns\binary\SQLSVR\setup.exe /QUIET  /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ConfigurationFile=C:\Users\UNIT-TEST\AppData\Local\Temp\Unit\DimIns\binary\SQLSVR\dimsqlsetup.ini /ACTION=Install" "" "C:\Users\UNIT-TEST\AppData\Local\Temp\Unit\DimIns\MsSQLServer2008R2.log"
```

or run it from the CMD

```
C:\Users\UNIT-TEST\AppData\Local\Temp\Unit\DimIns\binary\SQLSVR\setup.exe /QUIET  /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ConfigurationFile=C:\Users\UNIT-TEST\AppData\Local\Temp\Unit\DimIns\binary\SQLSVR\dimsqlsetup.ini /ACTION=Install
```

Then the installer install MS SQL correctly. So I can't imagine anyting else that the `$TEMP` or the `$OUTDIR` resolved in a bad way by NSIS. Is it possible or where is the problem?

If I write out the content of the `$TEMP` or the `$OUTDIR` to the console log its looks like they store the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

I do not like the syntax of your command. Use this syntax:

```
 nsExec::ExecToStack [OPTIONS] '"PATH" param1 param2 paramN'
```

to be sure all parameters and paths are treated correctly.

There is probably space in your path which is causing a trouble.

Comment: I use ExecDos::exec correctly. Anyway I have tried what you adviced but I get still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding extra quotes for all paths?

```
ExecDos::exec '"$OUTDIR\binary\SQLSVR\setup.exe" /QUIET /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ConfigurationFile="$OUTDIR\binary\SQLSVR\dimsqlsetup.ini" /ACTION=Install' "" "$OUTDIR\MsSQLServer2008R2.log"
```

Comment: Still not work. I made some further research, and it seems only the place of the binary matter. I can use the `$OUTDIR` in the path of the configuration, and the log, but when I put it in the path of the setup.exe the installer will fail the error I mentioned above in the question.